# Dropdown options based one external source and previous made choices?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-select

Ok, this might be confusing. Let me try to explain:

A client of mine asked me to create a solution generator. This simply said is a generator that supplies you with a solution, based on the answers you give to a few closed (dropdown) question. Though, the options of each question that are offered depend on the answer you gave on the previous question.

For instance: Question A gives you '1', '2', and '3'. Choosing '1' gives the options 10-15, but if you choose '2', you'd be given the options 16-20. If you choose 2, then 17, then you'd be given the options 110-120, but if you chose 2, followed by 16, you'd be given 100-109. And finally: The answer on the third question puts out an answer, which is connected to the answer on question 3. For instance; choosing 117 at the end will give you 'soap', while choosing 104 at the third question would say to you 'Give your wife a present'.

Simply said: Three(or perhaps more) dropdowns, which options given depend on the choice made in the previous dropdown. Where the last question and chosen answer will supply you with an answer, based on the final choice made.

The problem here is: I'm unsure where to start. I know this can be achieved with HTML and Javascript, but the options of the dropdown should be user-friendly editable. Therefor, HTML isn't my best bet and an Excel sheet would be easiar. But then my problem would be: How to let HTML depend on an excel sheet..

Therefor my question is: What's my best bet? What should I use for optimal result in both Web-friendly and user-friendly?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery script which you may appreciate. It is called jQuery Related Selects. I've used it in the past, works wonders. [Try the demo here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-related-selects/).

Comment: This seems interesting.. However..still should check how this is user friendly *and haven't found out in 30 seconds :) *

Comment: Obviously, having multiple dropdowns is rarely optimal, but there is a limit as to how user friendly you may need to be. I guess this should really be a case-by-case scenario, but (I think) this does get the result you want. User-friendliness is important, but at some point, the information has to be obtained, and I think this script does that quite well. I also think it's a good compromise: your drop downs don't go on forever, which is good in itself, you can seperate your code well and will be much clearer for the user.